# strange exception in android development,maybe caused by handler

Tags: java, android

Here is the exception content:

```
12-03 17:05:21.578    7214-7424/com.android.servermonitor.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12599
Process: com.android.servermonitor.app, PID: 7214
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.android.servermonitor.app.GetPushService$3.run(GetPushService.java:85)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Now I put all the code here:

```
public class GetPushService extends Service {
    private XMPPConnection connection;
    private SmackAndroid smackAndroid;
    private String[] user_info;
    private Handler login_handler,msg_handler;
    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int args0,int args1){
    this.user_info = intent.getStringArrayExtra("USERINFO");
    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    login_handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if (msg.what == -1){
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("Login Complete",1);
                intent.setAction("com.android.servermonitor.app.LOGIN_COMPLETE");
                sendBroadcast(intent);
                getPush();
            }
        }
    };
    msg_handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            if (msg.what == 1){
                String title = "Notification";
                String content = (String)msg.obj;
                Intent intent = new Intent(GetPushService.this,LoginActivity.class);
                PendingIntent launch = PendingIntent.getActivity(GetPushService.this,0,intent,0);
                notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(GetPushService.this)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setContentText(content)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentIntent(launch)
                        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

                notificationManager.notify(1,builder.build());
            }
        }
    };
    smackAndroid = SmackAndroid.init(this);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection = ConnectManager.connect(user_info[2], Contract.SERVER_PORT);
            ConnectManager.login(connection,user_info[0],user_info[1]);
            login_handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);
        }
    }).start();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            connection.disconnect();
            smackAndroid.onDestroy();
        }
    }).start();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

the exception happens at:

> connection = ConnectManager.connect(user_info[2], Contract.SERVER_PORT);

This exception won't happen everytime,it often hanppens

Comment: where is user_info declared?

Comment: NPE is one of the easiest problems to solve! It gives you the exact line where somethis is NULL. If it is your variable, it is not set. If it is result of an API call, read the manual to see the possible results and add a check condition.

Comment: it's no a strange exception it's a NullpointerException . It may be caused due to initialization, that u have not done

Comment: I declared it in somewhere else

Comment: Well, you have two options for the "somewhere else" code: show us or find someone else who can help... :-/

Comment: Now I put all all the code above

Comment: So as I said: If it is result of an API call (here intent.getStringArrayExtra()) you have to be sure it is not NULL or add a check condition. Who fills this Intent?

Comment: I'll have a try,Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check if

```
this.user_info = intent.getStringArrayExtra("USERINFO");
```

does not return null. This is an external interface for you Activity which should be checked for valid input or you have to check all fillings of intents whether they set this extra in the intents.